# How do you clear a specific bit in a register without changing the other bits in ONE instruction?

Tags: hex, bit, cpu-registers, lc3

For example, let's say register 4 (R4) has a value 0001110010101111. How could you change bit 5 (0001110010 >**1**< 01111) to 0 (even if it was already 0) without moving or changing the other bits **in a single hex instruction**?

So 0001110010**1**01111 -> 0001110010**0**01111

Comment: Look up `AND` for your assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to `AND` it. Since the immediate value for `AND` is 5 bits and it uses sign extension, you can only clear a bit if it's one of the four least significant bits. Otherwise, you will need to perform another instruction to load the mask into a register. I'll do an example of both.

In the case of the 5th bit, the number that will mask the bit is `0b1111111111011111`. In decimal, this is `#65503` or `#-33`. Since this is too big to fit in an immediate instruction, you won't be able to do it in a single instruction. You will need to declare it in the data segment of your program and load the mask into a register. Then, you can `AND` it with `R4`.

```
; assuming R4 = 0001110010101111
LD R5, MASK_5  ; load the mask into R5
AND R4, R4, R5 ; set R4 = R4 AND R5
               ; R4 will now have the bit cleared

; data segment
MASK_5 .FILL #65503
```

In the case of the 3rd bit, the number that will mask the bit is `0b1111111111110111`. In decimal, this is `#65527` or `#-9`. This will fit in the immediate value of `AND`, so you can perform it in a single instruction:

```
; assuming R4 = 0001110010101111
AND R4, R4, #-9 ; set R4 = R4 AND #-9
                ; R4 will now have the bit cleared
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require two hex instructions? One for LD and another for AND?

Comment: Good point. I interpreted the question to mean that they don't want to check if the bit was set before subtracting it to clear it. I can't think of a way to do it in a single instruction in LC3 unless the bit is one of the four least significant bits.